# How to focus input date field in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, semantics

Could you please tell me How to focus input date field in react?I am using a plugin of semantic
https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui-calendar-react

I want to focus date input field on button click here is my code.
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/3l414mno5

```
focus = () => {
    console.log(this.a);
    this.a[0].onFocus();
    // this.inputRef.focus()
  };
```

the focus is not coming in input field why?
any update ?

Comment: are you expecting a solution like this https://codesandbox.io/s/j4nloxq1m5 ?

Comment: but if I have 50 date field the i need to create 50 create ref.solution is correct.But implementation

Comment: is there any better way to do the same thinh

Comment: you can create dynamic refs instead. Is my solution helpful ?

Comment: @tanmay you can check this https://github.com/arfedulov/semantic-ui-calendar-react/blob/master/src/views/InputView.tsx  and you  can check the console of this.logButton.current , it gives available options

Comment: You can use autoFocus prop to focus the input

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/3l414mno5

Comment: why it is not working here https://codesandbox.io/s/3l414mno5 `focus = () => {
    console.log(this.a);
    this.a[0].logButton.current.openPopup()();
    // this.inputRef.focus()
  };`

Comment: I tried without using createRef

Comment: @user944513 Refer to [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jlwky70m53?fontsize=14) for autofocus

Comment: @jayaval done thanks for help

Comment: YES..THANKS FOR HELP

Comment: YES SURE..YOU CAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable a focus on button click, you need to set a ref like this :

```
    this.logButton = React.createRef();
    ref={this.logButton}
```

and access it in button click like below:

```
focus = e => {
    this.logButton.current.openPopup();
};
```

`openPopup()`  - is a fucntion to open the calendar popup, the plugin your using, has code like this, check [here](https://github.com/arfedulov/semantic-ui-calendar-react/blob/master/src/views/InputView.tsx)

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4nloxq1m5) and In multiple data fields, use dynamic refs. Hope it helps.